# Extracting Names and Email address from String with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have been trying to extract the names and email addresses from the following String that consists of multiple lines through regex in Java:

```
From: Kane Smith <Kane@smith.com>
To: John Smith <john@smith.com>, Janes Smith
    <jane@smith.org>, Tom Barter <tom@test.co.uk>, Other
    Weird @#$@<>#^Names <other@names.me>, 
    Long Long Long Long Name <longlong@name.com>
Date: Tue, 25 Oct 2011 15:45:59 +0000
```

I tried this regex: `To:\s?(([.*]+)\s*<([\w\d@\.]*)>,(\s|\n)*)+`
But it doesn't work.

My intention is to extract each of the names and email addresses and put each name its email address together into groups. What I have done however, seems to work only when there is one single name and address. What should my regex be to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
    String s = "To: John Smith <john@smith.com>, Janes Smith\n"
            + "<jane@smith.org>, Tom Barter <tom@test.co.uk>, Other \n"
            + "Weird @#$@<>#^Names <other@names.me>, \n"
            + "Long Long Long Long Name <longlong@name.com>";
    s = s.substring(3); // filter TO:
    System.out.println(s);
    // Use DOTALL pattern  
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)<([^>]+)>\\s*,?",Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while(m.find()) {
        // filter newline
        String name = m.group(1).replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", ""); 
        String email = m.group(2).replaceAll("[\\n\\r]+", "");
        System.out.println(name + " -> " + email);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But because this was actually from an email header, I may not be able to do a substring and then replaceAll after that. I updated my question on the search string to show that because what's above the To and below the To, there are also other contents. Is is possible for me to still extract them out if the To is not just as clean?

Comment: why don't you use an other regex to get "TO" content and then use this code to extract emails and names?

Comment: @Fred: What happens if the Subject or the name or if there is another header say `Delivery-To:`, I will get more than just one content for searching the "To".

Comment: Also, if the name consist of a `<` character, the regex would match wrongly too.

Answer (score 1):

you can split each line on "," and then use javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress. That will take care of extracting the name and address.

Btw, where are you getting the headers from and why can't they be key values as they should be?

Comment: The content is directly from the POP. I don't intend to use the javamail library.