# find emails in a String

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get emails from a String which is like:

`"***  test@gmail.com&&^ test2@gmail.com((& ";`

```
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)");
```

The code above can get one email.

How can I get all?

Comment: You can use pattern class in java 


[see here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899116/extracting-names-and-email-address-from-string-with-regex

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899116/extracting-names-and-email-address-from-string-with-regex

Comment: I'm not sure the `+` char is allowed in emails.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

try

```
    String s = "*** test@gmail.com&&^ test2@gmail.com((& ";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: Solution at this link is perfect, https://handyopinion.com/utility-method-to-get-all-email-addresses-from-a-string-in-java/

Comment: This is a Kotlin function using the answer:

@JvmStatic
        fun extractEmails(text: String): MutableList<String> {
            val list = mutableListOf<String>()
            val m: Matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(text)
            while (m.find()) {
                list.add(m.group())
            }
            return list
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `^` and `$` anchors.